# Firebase / iOS & push app server: Are there any service providers?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

I want the users of my app to be notified about new chat messages. Apparently clients cannot send push notifications with Firebase. As far as I could understand I need another server for this (so called `appserver`?).

This is quite a bit of disappointing because I assumed that with the relaunch of Firebase client initiated push would work without 3rd party services. Am I wrong or is this currently not possible with Firebase? If it is not possible, what are recommandable services? Would `parse push server` work with Firebase?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37481992/firebase-chat-push-notifications/37484156#37484156