# Firebase: How to observe a node and send push notifications to clients?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

Since the new release of Firebase you are able to send push notifications from the console to specified clients with `Firebase Notifications`. But for a chat app I need Firebase to watch a node for new children and send the push notifications to those clients.

Is Firebase capable of this and if yes what is the best way to do this?

Comment: you will need a custom server to manage the push notifications.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37481992/firebase-chat-push-notifications/37484156#37484156

Answer (score -1):

With Firebase client sdk you can register listeners for node events on the client side. Then Firebase will do the magic to notify the client on node events.

Comment: I want to send iOS push notifications to users, when the app is closed.

Comment: @MJQZ1347 got it. You can send push messages to iOS using Firebase.
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-ios-swift/#6

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client

Comment: @gipsy sending messages through the firebase database will only work when the app is active. Firebase notifications and firebase cloud messaging  allow the app to receive messages when it's not active, but not to send them from device to device. Sending messages in that scenario requires access to a trusted key, which means it should only be done in a trusted process.